# I want to clear my table before adding new data in that particular table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to clear my table before adding new data in that particular table.

After that the data which is already there has to be moved to another table before clear the table.

`table1->Insert new data and move old data to table2`

`table2->old data of table1 + new data of table1`

Comment: And what do you expect from us?? To make your work? You should tell us what have your done, what have you tried, errors you get , how your tabkles are created and so on ...

Comment: Are you replicating table1 data into table2 on a record by record basis in step 2?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am not replicating table1 data into table2.
Only once it will replicating after that only adding.for example in table 2 have data 10 and after that data of table 1 is coming than data of table2 will be 20.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

1. Move old data to table2
2. Delete data in table1
3. Insert new data in table1

Based on the steps you outline, there wouldn't be any difference between table 1 and table 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$query = "Insert into table_2 Select * from table_1";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_query("Truncate table table_1");
```